# c function not being called?

Tags: c, function

I have basically no experience in c, so i'm not sure why this isn't working.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a=1; 
int b=5;

void fact(a,b) {

    if(b == 1) {
        return;
    } else {
        a = a * b;
        b = b - 1;
        fact(a, b);
    }
}

int main() {

    fact(a, b); 
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

The program should call fact recursively until a becomes 120. However it prints 1. I'm not sure why this is happening so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The function is passed *copies* of `a` and `b` and passes nothing back. The `a` and `b` in the function are different variables from the global ones of the same name, having only local scope (and life).

Comment: The parameter variables `a` and `b` inside the function shadow the global variables with the same names.

Comment: Does this code compile?

Comment: @Jay: What is the issue? It compiles for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing copy of variables a and b. Pass Variables as a pointer, if you want to update the value .
Modified the code below -

```
void fact(int *a, int *b) {

    if(*b == 1) {
        return;
    } else {

        *a = *a * *b;
        *b = *b - 1;
        fact(a, b);
        }
    }

    int main() {

        fact(&a, &b);
        printf("%d", a);
    }
```

You can visit the below link -

[How to update the value in another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667497/update-int-variable-in-c-inside-a-function)

Comment: Since a and b are global variables, just changing 
`void fact(a,b) {` to 
`void fact(c,d) {` gives output 120! :P But your answer is correct.

Comment: You can pass `b` by value; it's only `a` that's mutating.

Comment: @sas: You are still doing pass by value. But you are passing memory address.

Answer (score 0):

This function definition (provided that the compiler accepts it)

```
void fact(a,b) {

if(b == 1) {
    return;
} else {

    a = a * b;
    b = b - 1;
    fact(a, b);
    }   
}
```

looks in fact the following way

```
void fact(a,b) 
int a, b;
{

if(b == 1) {
    return;
} else {

    a = a * b;
    b = b - 1;
    fact(a, b);
    }   
}
```

That is the variables `a` and `b` in the function definition are local variables of the function that have copies of the arguments supplied to the function by this call

```
fact(a, b);
```

Thus in the function call there are used global variables `a` and `b` but inside the function itself there are used local variables `a` and `b` that is copies of the global variables. Any changes of these local variables do not influence on the global variables.

How to resolve the problem?

The first approach is to remove the function parameters. In this case `a` and `b` inside the function definition will denote the global variables

```
void fact( void ) 
{

if(b == 1) {
    return;
} else {

    a = a * b;
    b = b - 1;
    fact(a, b);
    }   
}
```

and you will get the expected result.

The second approach is to use parameters but also to return the result. For example

int fact( a, b) 
int a, b;
{
if(b == 1) {
    return a;
} else {

```
a = a * b;
b = b - 1;
return fact(a, b);
}
```

}

and call the function the following way

```
a = fact( a, b );
```

However such a function definition is deprecated.

It would be better to write it like

```
int fact( int a, int b) 
{
if(b == 1) {
    return a;
} else {

    a = a * b;
    b = b - 1;
    return fact(a, b);
    }   
}
```

And the third approach is to pass arguments to the function by reference. For example

```
void fact( int *pa, int *pb ) 
{

if( *pb == 1) {
    return;
} else {

    *pa = *pa * b;
    *pb = *pb - 1;
    fact(pa, pb);
    }   
}
```

and call the function like

```
fact( &a, &b );
```

However it would be simpler to write the function the following way

```
int fact( int n )
{
    return n < 1 ? 1 : n * fact( n - 1 );
}
```

and call it like

```
a = fact( b );
```